# UITextView text gets cut weirdly the the frame width is big

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

I have a resize method where I make the TextView have bigger fonts and therefore a bigger frame. However, for widths higher than, say, 900 pixels, the text gets cut off. Screenshot below.

The cut-off occurs on the non-seen part of the screen and when I move in the textview inside the view port, it becomes visible.

Anyone experienced a similar strangeness? [image]g

Comment: It sounds like this is some kind of a graphics layer bug. Could you use UILabel or Core Text instead of UITextView?

Comment: I can, my UITextView is heavily customized and I don't wanna go into implementing a UILabel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My custom UITextView's are draggable.

I solved my problem by simply adding this line inside my pan gesture recognizer action.

```
self.frame = self.frame;
```

I guess this way, the text gets redrawn each time a pan occurs. Don't know what's going on behind the stage though... Strange.

Answer (score 0):

Set your view ports clipsToBounds property to NO.

```
viewPortThatContainsTheTextView.clipsToBounds = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

you could also write a if statement that sets the width and height of your UITextfield depending on the length of the text that is entered. can also be used with UILabel

for example:

```
UITextView * tv = [[UItextView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake
(x,y,textFILE.frame.size.Width,TextFile.frame.size.Height)]
```

where X and Y are some points within your view. What this does is give you a dynamically responsive text view that depends on the text inside your text view.

you could also do something like this for a UILabel, although this approach is more advanced using a datastructure like an arrray for this example.

```
UILabel *textLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initwithFrame:CGRectMake
(X,y,yourView.YourLabel.frame.size.width,[CurrentText objectAtIndex: 0].sizeWithFont:[UIFont 
fontwithName:@"times" size:12]constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(x,y).height)];
```

Comment: Yeah but there is no problem with setting the frame size according t o the text size. My problem is with the clipping off of text when it's off screen.

Comment: Solved yeah. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

CGSize requiredSize = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17]  constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(CGFLOAT_MAX, 200)];